# Eclipse Explorer covering up code screen in Java perspective

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse screen looks the same as always except for one thing.  The Java Explorer/Package explorer seem to be top level all the time and so they cover up part of the code screen. I don't know how to get back to default configuration?

Just to be clear, the rectangle with the explorer trees now is above all other screens, rather than to the left of the code screen. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Care to show us a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably dragged Package explorer to separate window or to a fast view. Solution is simple, just drag the view where it supposed to be. Eclipse should automatically snap it to the main window when dragged close enough to the edge.